# pipe from Python smtpd debugging server to file/database

Tags: python, linux, smtpd

is there a way to pipe the output from the Python smtpd debugging server

```
python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025
```

in a database/file?

I want to show all traffic on this port on a simple webpage. If there is a better way please let me know!

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to send the mail content to a file by using output redirection like this:

```
python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025 >> mail.txt
```

I would prefer to use `| tee mail.txt` instead of `>> mail.txt` (to also print the mail content to the command line) but that didn't work.

To your question, if you want to see all traffic on a specific port, you are probably looking for something like tcpdump:

```
tcpdump -i any port 1025
```